# Не могу разобраться с try-catch

Tags: c++, try-catch

Добрый вечер.
Есть самый простой кусок кода

```
int k = 0;
            for (double x = -2; x <= 2; x += 0.2)
            {
                try 
                {
                    mas_a[k] = sqrt(pow(x, 2) - 1);
                    k++;
                }
                catch (EDivByZero &e) //ловим деление на 0
                {
                    mas_a[k] = 0;
                    cout << "Деление на ноль целых чисел" << endl;
                    k++;
                }

                catch (EZeroDivide &e)
                {
                    mas_a[k] = 0;
                    cout << "Деление на ноль вещественных чисел" << endl;
                    k++;
                }
                cout << "[" << k << "]=>" << mas_a[k] << " | ";
}
```

Нужно в диапазоне [-2,2] с шагом 0.2 заполнить массив по функции sqrt(pow(x, 2) - 1).  И вылавливать исключения деления на 0. Написал, но ругается на EZeroDivide и EDivByZero.
Что не так?

Comment: Эти классы у вас определены? И, кстати, у вас нигде деления на ноль все равно нет. И, еще раз кстати, нет никакого смысла в `pow(x,2)` - `x*x` и короче, и быстрее.

Comment: Так а что такое `EDivByZero` и `EZeroDivide`? И где у вас вообще какое-то выбрасывание исключений?

Answer (score 3):

Никаких исключений `EDivByZero` и `EZeroDivide` нет. Это С++, а не delphi. Более того, деление на 0 никакого исключения в С++ [не производит](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747934/c-catch-a-divide-by-zero-error) (для встроенных типов). Это в С++ не то, за что отвечают исключения, а ошибка, за которую должен отвечать программист, чтобы такого не допускать.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать в таком случае что-то такое:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   try{
        int i = 0; //для проверки
        if(!i) throw invalid_argument("division by zero");
        else cout<<(double)1/i<<endl;
   }

   catch(invalid_argument& oop){
        cout<<oop.what()<<endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```